# How to change default images of CheckBox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using ListView and for every row I have row_item.xml and I inflate that in code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChoice"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

How to change that checkBox use another custom_1 image when is checked and another custom_2 image when is unchecked ?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Drawable **customdrawablecheckbox.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_drawable" />
     <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked_drawable" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_drawable" /> <!-- default state -->
</selector>
```

yourcheckbox xml:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chk"
    android:button="@drawable/customdrawablecheckbox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I have to programmatically gen checkbox how do I use custom checkBox anyone has an idea?

Comment: If I do on the Checkbox : android:state_checked="false"  by default it doesn't work

Comment: How to set padding for this drawable?

Comment: how to give padding to this image?

Comment: Nice and clean, +1. Could someone by any chance provide an answer that would include the transition flashing effect that android default checkboxes have? I thought maybe the "android:state_pressed" or "android:state_focused" attributes could be used so I played around with them, but without any luck.

Answer (score 9):

checkbox is a button, so you can provide your own drawable with check uncheck state and it as checkbox background. For instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable1" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable1" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

and put this in a file.xml in your drawable folder. In your checkbox:

```
  <CheckBox
    android:button="@drawable/file"
    android:id="@+id/chk"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: android:background doesn't run with the checkbutton image , it puts another image on the background view .

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty easy :) 
First you need to create a CustomCheckBox class which will extend CheckBox and override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckBox {
private final Drawable buttonDrawable;

public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
    buttonDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_check_box);
    try {
        setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
    setPadding(10, 5, 50, 5);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    buttonDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());

    final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    final int height = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    if (buttonDrawable != null) {
        int y = 0;

        switch (verticalGravity) {
        case Gravity.BOTTOM:
            y = getHeight() - height;
            break;
        case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
            y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
            break;
        }

        int buttonWidth = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int buttonLeft = getWidth() - buttonWidth - 5;
        buttonDrawable.setBounds(buttonLeft, y, buttonLeft + buttonWidth, y + height);
        buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
}
```

Also create your selector named `custom_check_box` in your drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />    
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />
</selector>
```

And use your custom icons/imgs in the XML above for all three states (focused/pressed/default)

Use the custom component in your XML like this :

```
<*package + class path*.CustomCheckBox   // example com.mypackage.ui.CustomCheckBox if your project is named "mypackage" and the class is in the "ui" folder
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:checked="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myCheckbox" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and java :

```
private CustomCheckBox mCheckbox;
mCheckbox = (CustomCheckBox) findviewbyid(R.id.myCheckbox);
```

It works because I used it both ways :) And with some tweaks it works for RadioButtons too the same way. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector in xml, which is used to change the image of checkbox dynamically according to its checked state.

For example:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_linkedin" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_linkedin_disabled" android:state_checked="false" />
```

In the following file, if the checkbox is checked, it will set the ic_linkedin icon and if the checkbox is unchecked, it will set the ic_linkedin_disabled icon.