# Reduce Check box size in android?

Tags: android

i have tried out the suggestions given but unable to reduce the size...on reduction of size in graphical layout,the border lines of the checkbox disappear...iam new to android...any help will be appreciated

thanks

here is code...

```
   <LinearLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#F3CAE5"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="8dp" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000" />





<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_fName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000" />





  </LinearLayout>
```

height and width change removes the border lines...check box appears in a list view that is populated dynamically...

the below code works for changing the checkbox image but now iam unable to check the box ie the tick mark does not appear on checking the box???

Comment: have you tried to give the height like 2dp or 3dp ??

Comment: Please post some screenshots so that one can understand your problem. which suggestion you have tried?

Comment: I think you have to place your custom image for that. here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7783892/1395259

Comment: the below code works for changing the checkbox image but now iam unable to check the box ie the tick mark does not appear on checking the box...

Answer (score 0):

The text determines the size of the check box. try this:

```
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="new checkbox" 
    ....... />
```

Answer (score 0):

use custom image for check box 
and use image of  your size

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
 <item android:state_checked="false"

  android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
</selector>
```