# ImageView on again click

Tags: java, android, xml

I want my `ImageView` to change it's `drawable` resource as it is pressed. The problem occurs when `ImageView` is pressed for the second time.

Let me explain, if `ImageView` is pressed first time, I want it to change from `drawable` A to `drawable` B. If `ImageView` is pressed again I want it to change from `drawable` B to `drawable` A.

That pressed again part is not working..

## Here's my code:

```
public void imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMarkMetoda(View view){
        imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark);
        if (view == imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark){
            imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_biljeske_obavljeno);
        } else {
            imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_biljeske_nije_obavljeno);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: it sounds like a check box

Comment: Yes but I would preffer it to be with custom drawable

Comment: You can make checkbox do that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783787/how-to-change-default-images-of-checkbox

Comment: Then use a selector to change the button drawable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this from the method.... 
You need to init the object once  in the onCreate...

```
imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark);
```

Then add a boolean variable to control the state of the view. .

```
public void imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMarkMetoda(View view){
        flag =!flag;

        if (view == imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark){
          if (flag) {imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_biljeske_obavljeno);
        } else {
            imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_biljeske_nije_obavljeno);
        } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is that flag?

Comment: A boolean value to control the state of the view

Comment: Declare it as a variable in the activity... boolean flag;

Comment: Yeah but flag !=flag is still not a statement

Answer (score 1):

I sugggest to use the "tag" of the view, and keep in the tag the information you need (e.g. if the view is pressed or not)

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a toggle method like this?

```
private void toggleDrawableOnClick(){

    /* now you can check to see if the set drawable is A using its id */
    if(visible drawable is A){
      imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_biljeske_nije_obavljeno);
    }else{
      imageViewBiljeskeNaListiCheckMark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_biljeske_obavljeno);
    }
}
```

This should be easier I believe!!