# How to set the default background for android checkbox

Tags: android, android-checkbox

***I have***

```
Checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_checkbox_disabled);
```

***Here i am setting to custom image***

---

### How to set to default check box background

**I tried:**

```
Checkbox.setButtonDrawable(null);
```

But entire box diseappered
So I need the resource name of the checkbox android uses

---

Something like:

```
Checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.android.resourcename);
```

**Any solution for this**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default images of CheckBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783787/how-to-change-default-images-of-checkbox)

Comment: Try {Checkbox.setButtonDrawable(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background)}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new selector file in drawable folder with name **checkbox_selection** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" 
              android:state_checked="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck" 
              android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>    
    </selector>
```

Modify your checkbox view in xml file as show below :

```
<CheckBox
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selection"
     android:text="CheckBox"
     android:textColor="@color/Black" >
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: When will `checkbox` drawable be used? The `state_checked="true"` already covers all the rest cases, no? Also, I think the drawable names are the opposite of what you intended (`checked` is for when it's unchecked, and vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

In drawable folder, make one file and name anything you want. Then paste this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked_icon" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked_icon" android:state_checked="false"/>


</selector>
```

**radio_checked_icon and 
radio_unchecked_icon, these are the custom images you want to put, when your checkbox is clicked, then radio_checked_icon, else radio_unchecked_icon**

and then in layout use like this:

```
 <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/tiny_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:button="@drawable/name_of_your_file_present_in_Drawable"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_short" />
```