# How to create Rectangle custom Radio Button or CheckBox?

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button

How can I create a custom checkbox like the given image? Should I do it with radio button as the filling of color looks like a radio button? If yes, how to do it using radio button?

[image: Custom checkbox]

Comment: Did you try this [How to change default images of CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7783892/13502627)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can start from here

1. Create custom drawable, `your_awesome_checkbox.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
>     <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_awesome_chb_checked" />
>     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_awesome_chb_checked" />
>     <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_awesome_chb_unchecked" />
> </selector>
> ```

And set this drawable to your checkboxes like

```
android:button="@drawable/your_awesome_checkbox"
```

In above code

1. ic_awesome_chb_checked: This icon represents the selected state of the checkbox. Like the state which you have added to your question.
2. ic_awesome_chb_unchecked: Represents default state of Checkbox, unselected.